# Javascript Getting value from exact field from associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an associative array - indexed by dates. Every element holds another array.

[03/16/2015: Array[3], 03/17/2015: Array[3], 03/18/2015: Array[3], 03/19/2015: Array[3]]

I created it with this code:

```
 array[cellDate][i]=cellText;
```

How can I get the value for example from cell 03/16/2015 array[2] ??

```
 var text=array['03/16/2015'][2];
```

With this line of code I got an error.

EDIT:

http://www.traineffective.com/schedule/

I store in that array title of blocks dropped in the schedule (title of block of 'empty' value if cell is empty)

What I want to achive is remeber the order of the blocks for particular weeks , and when user changes week with arrows it loads block based on date withdrowed from array.

Code where I create array  :

```
function saveWeekToArray(array){
    var cellDate;
    var cellText;
    var tmpText;
    var i;
    workoutsTD.each(function(){
        cellDate=$(this).attr("data-day");
        array[cellDate]=['','',''];
        i=0;
        $(this).children('.workout-cell').each(function(){ 
            if (!$(this).hasClass('workout-cell-empty')){
                cellText=$(this).find('span').text();
                array[cellDate][i]=cellText;
            } else {
                array[cellDate][i]='empty';
            }
            i++
        });

    });
}
```

Code where I load data from array (One with the error )

```
function loadBlocksFromArray(array){
    var cellDate;
    var cellText;
    var tmpText;
    var i;
    workoutsTD.each(function(){
        cellDate=$(this).attr("data-day");
        i=0;
        $(this).children('.workout-cell').each(function(){ 
            if ((array[cellDate][i])!='empty'){
                cellText=array[cellDate][i];
                $(this).append(createBlock(cellText));
                $(this).removeClass('workout-cell-empty');
            }
            i++;
        });

    });
}
```

When you will click sumbit button in console log you will see the structure of array.

I got error while changing the week its :

`enter code here`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: It would be really helpful if you tell us the error.

Comment: Or what code you're trying to use.

Comment: Added code and the error

Comment: That simply means you are trying to access a property that does not exist. Example: `var foo = {}; foo.bar[0];`. Solution: Ensure the property you want to access exists. Either the object you are creating is incorrect or `cellDate` has the wrong value. Not much we can do here, since we don't know they value of either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, there is no concept of an associative array. You either have arrays (which are indexed by numbers) or you have Objects (whose elements are indexed by strings).

What you instead want is an object containing all of your arrays. For example:

```
var data = {
  '3/4/2015' : ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'],
  '3/8/2015' : ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
};
```

Then you can access your elements in the way that you want:

```
var ele = data['3/4/2015'][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/x9dnwgwc/

That is the effect what I wanted achive. Thanks for hint Harvtronix!

```
var jsonObj = { workout : {} }

var i;
var k;
var workoutArray = [];

for(i=1; i<=7; i++){
    var newWorkout = i+ "/12/2015";
        for (k=0; k<=2; k++){    
            var newValue = "workoutTitle" + k;
            workoutArray[k]=newValue;
        }
    jsonObj.workout[newWorkout]=workoutArray;

}

console.log(jsonObj);

for(i=1; i<=7; i++){
  var newWorkout = i+ "/12/2015"; 
   var tmpArray= jsonObj.workout[newWorkout];
     console.log(tmpArray);

}
```